# Mixing of localhost (default for [NDBD]HostName) with other hostname(X.X.X.X) is illegal

Tags: mysql-cluster

I'm trying to create a mysql cluster configuration between two servers has mysql server 5.5 installed.

on the main server I execute the ndb management server using the following command:

```
ndb_mgmd -f conf/config.ini --initial --configdir=/storage-mysql/mysql_cluster/conf
```

my config.ini in the main server is: (changed my ip to X.X.X.X)

```
[computer]
id=db02
hostname=X.X.X.X

[ndb_mgmd]
 hostname=localhost
 datadir=/storage-mysql/mysql_cluster/ndb_data
 nodeid=1
[ndbd default]
 noofreplicas=2
 datadir=/storage-mysql/mysql_cluster/ndb_data
[ndbd]
   hostname=localhost
   nodeid=3
[ndbd]
    ExecuteOnComputer=db02
    hostname=localhost
    nodeid=4
[mysqld]
   nodeid=50
```

when I execute the sndb_mgmd server i get the following error:

```
2011-10-02 14:09:47 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- at line 9: Mixing of localhost (default for [NDBD]HostName) with other hostname(X.X.X.X) is illegal
2011-10-02 14:09:47 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- at line 9: Could not store previous default section of configuration file.
2011-10-02 14:09:47 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- Could not load configuration from 'conf/config.ini'
2011-10-02 14:09:47 [MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- Could not determine which nodeid to use for this node. Specify it with --ndb-nodeid=<nodeid> on command line
```

what am I doing wrong?

using MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.1.56 ndb-7.1.15a

thank you!

kfir

Comment: As it says: Don't put localhost in your configuration file.

Comment: i thought that I can't mix two ip address on the same config file. thanks :) please add it as answer so i'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says: Don't put localhost in your configuration file.